# PHP PDO connection error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to connect to my DB with `PDO` and I'm keep getting "not connected" all the time and can´t understand why!!

Here is my code:

```
class Connect{

    private $connect;

    function dbConnect(){

        try{
            $this->connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Demo1", 'root', '');
            $this->connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            echo "connected";

        }catch(PDOException $ex){
            $ex->getMessage();
            echo "not connected";
        }
    }
}
```

Why am I falling in to the exception?

Comment: write `echo`before `$ex->getMessage();` and post the error message.

Comment: In your catch block do `echo $ex->getMessage();` and it should explain you what's going on.

Comment: Echo the $ex->GetMessage() as well and you will see why the connection fails.

Comment: aaaah i forgot to echo it!
Ok i solved it now!
Thank you everyone!